# Grouping specific type of data and sorting them in ascending or descending order using lodash

Tags: javascript, momentjs, lodash

I would like to group below JSON based on the "title" and "alertID" and then sort it in ascending or descending order.

```
    let events = [{
    "_id": "5cbdb030284dfeb0bb441bfe",
    "alert": {
        "title": "New Pt w/ discharge in last 30 days",
        "alertTime": "2018-12-15T05:48:31.000Z",
        "alertID": "99994444"
    }
}, {
    "_id": "5cbdafbc284dfeb0bb441bd7",
    "alert": {
        "title": "Insurance: Non-Contracted Plan",
        "alertTime": "2018-09-01T03:13:00.000Z",
        "alertID": "12345699"
    }
}, {
    "_id": "5cbdafbe284dfeb0bb441be6",
    "alert": {
        "title": "Insurance: Non-Contracted Plan",
        "alertTime": "2018-09-01T03:13:00.000Z",
        "alertID": "12345688"
    }
}, {
    "_id": "5cbdb08d284dfeb0bb441c13",
    "alert": {
        "title": "New Pt w/ ED visit in last 7 days",
        "alertTime": "2018-12-15T05:48:31.000Z",
        "alertID": "12345699"
    }
}, {
    "_id": "5cbdb068284dfeb0bb441c09",
    "alert": {
        "title": "New Pt w/ ED visit in last 7 days",
        "alertTime": "2018-12-15T05:48:31.000Z",
        "alertID": "12345688"
    }
}, {
    "_id": "5cbdb477284dfeb0bb441c73",
    "alert": {
        "title": "PT Consult Order",
        "alertTime": "2018-07-17T05:42:15.000Z",
        "alertID": "12345699"
    }
}, {
    "_id": "5cbdafb8284dfeb0bb441bc7",
    "alert": {
        "title": "Bed Request Order for Medicare Patient",
        "alertTime": "2019-04-22T12:12:39.340Z",
        "alertID": "99994444"
    }
}]
```

This is how i trying to achieve (descending order) it but it not getting sorted.

```
_(events)
            .orderBy(events, (e) => { return e.alert.alertTime},['desc'])
            .uniqBy(function(event) { return [event.alert.title, event.alert.alertID].join();})
            .groupBy((event) => event.alert.alertID)
```

I specifically wanted to use lodash to achieve this requirement. Can someone please point out what i am missing?

**This is a desired output that i am expecting. So if "alertID: 99994444" comes first then i would like to group all the data having same 'alertID' and sort them in ascending or descending order like shown below. Similarly this should be done for all the remaining 'alertID'.**:

```
[{
    "_id": "5cbdb477284dfeb0bb441c73",
    "alert": {
        "title": "PT Consult Order",
        "alertTime": "2018-07-17T05:42:15.000Z",
        "alertID": "12345699"
    }
}, {
    "_id": "5cbdafbc284dfeb0bb441bd7",
    "alert": {
        "title": "Insurance: Non-Contracted Plan",
        "alertTime": "2018-09-01T03:13:00.000Z",
        "alertID": "12345699"
    }
}, {
    "_id": "5cbdb08d284dfeb0bb441c13",
    "alert": {
        "title": "New Pt w/ ED visit in last 7 days",
        "alertTime": "2018-12-15T05:48:31.000Z",
        "alertID": "12345699"
    }
}, {
    "_id": "5cbdafbe284dfeb0bb441be6",
    "alert": {
        "title": "Insurance: Non-Contracted Plan",
        "alertTime": "2018-09-01T03:13:00.000Z",
        "alertID": "12345688"
    }
}, {
    "_id": "5cbdb068284dfeb0bb441c09",
    "alert": {
        "title": "New Pt w/ ED visit in last 7 days",
        "alertTime": "2018-12-15T05:48:31.000Z",
        "alertID": "12345688"
    }
}, {
    "_id": "5cbdb030284dfeb0bb441bfe",
    "alert": {
        "title": "New Pt w/ discharge in last 30 days",
        "alertTime": "2018-12-15T05:48:31.000Z",
        "alertID": "99994444"
    }
}, {
    "_id": "5cbdafb8284dfeb0bb441bc7",
    "alert": {
        "title": "Bed Request Order for Medicare Patient",
        "alertTime": "2019-04-22T12:12:39.340Z",
        "alertID": "99994444"
    }
}]
```

Comment: Please post the expected output

Comment: @adiga i have added the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you use chaining with `_(events)`, you should omit the first "collection" argument from the chained method calls. So change:

```
_(events)
        .orderBy(events, (e) => { return e.alert.alertTime},['desc'])
```

to:

```
_(events)
        .orderBy((e) => { return e.alert.alertTime},['desc'])
```

Comment: I tried this but still facing same issue. I have also added desired output in the question.